# How to assign a random integer to every object in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

`Edited to include a reproducible example.` 
When a new task is created, a quantity can be input to create multiple tasks with the same data. In this case, the `quantity` is 3, so three tasks will be created with the other `name:value` pairs within the `newtaskconfig` object. The quantity is used in the for loop to push that many tasks to the `newtasks` array. An id with a random three digit integer is then assigned to each object within the `newtasks` array.

```js
newtaskconfig = {
  site: 'YeezySupply',
  findby: 'URL',
  urlorpid: 'test.com',
  useproxies: 'TRUE',
  quantity: 3
}
quantity = Number(newtaskconfig.quantity)
delete newtaskconfig.quantity
newtasks=[]
for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++)  
{ 
  newtasks.push(newtaskconfig)
}
newtasks.forEach(task=>{
  task.id=Math.floor(Math.random()*(900)+100)
})
```

When I then log the newtasks array to console, instead of each object having a unique id, they all end up with the exact same one, shown here:

```js
[
  {
    site: 'YeezySupply',
    findby: 'URL',
    urlorpid: 'test.com',
    useproxies: 'TRUE',
    id: 346
  },
  {
    site: 'YeezySupply',
    findby: 'URL',
    urlorpid: 'test.com',
    useproxies: 'TRUE',
    id: 346
  },
  {
    site: 'YeezySupply',
    findby: 'URL',
    urlorpid: 'test.com',
    useproxies: 'TRUE',
    id: 346
  }
]
```

How can I change my approach so that each object within the array is assigned a unique three digit id?

Comment: It seems like the problem is that your array contains multiple references to the *same object*. Or you were just very unlucky.

Comment: Your "array of objects" is just an array of three pointers to the same object.

Comment: Yes, as these are three unique tasks, which is why I am intending to assign them a unique id.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you're saying yes to. You might consider them unique tasks, but it seems like they're actually not even separate objects. Give a [mre], if you create them with literals as shown, the code you've posted *works*.

Comment: I have tried my best to edit my question to provide this, please let me know if you need more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line to `newtasks.push({...newtaskconfig})`, instead of `newtasks.push(newtaskconfig)` which causing have same ref.

Update: as @jonrsharpe suggest, simplify the code to the following.

```js
newtaskconfig = {
  site: "YeezySupply",
  findby: "URL",
  urlorpid: "test.com",
  useproxies: "TRUE",
  quantity: 3
};

const { quantity, ...rest } = newtaskconfig;
const newtasks = new Array(quantity)
  .fill(0)
  .map(() => ({ ...rest, id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 + 100) }));

console.log(newtasks);
```

Comment: You could simplify to `newtasks.push({ ...newtaskconfig, id: ... })`. Note that this is only a *shallow* clone.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, Updated answer to further simplify.